# Slick carousel arrows on inside of element

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

Is there a way to put the arrows for the Slick carousel on the inside of the element area they scroll on instead of outside?

Comment: Have you attempted to do this? What have you tried, if anything? Maybe provide markup of your specific carousel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little CSS maybe:

```
.slick-prev { left: 10px }
.slick-next { right: 10px }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would just like to use CSS you can just target the classes .slick-prev and .slick-next. Posting your code might help, but here is what worked on slick carousel's demo page (I had to add a background-color to for the white icon to show up on the white slide).

```
.slick-prev {left:10px;}
.slick-next {right: 10px;}
```